# Snowflake DDL not allowing to load data into table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Not able to insert data into Snowflake table with Specific data types

This may be very silly question but i just started trying out Snowflake and stuck at first step itself .
I need to look up XML element from the `DETAILS` column

```
select testId from app_event  table ;
```

This is how i am trying to create a table in Snowflake

```
create or replace table app_event (
  ID varchar(36)  not null primary key, 
  VERSION number, 
  ACT_TYPE varchar(255),
  EVE_TYPE varchar(255),
  CLI_ID varchar(36),
  DETAILS variant,
  OBJ_TYPE varchar(255),
  DATE_TIME timestamp,
  AAPP_EVENT_TO_UTC_DT timestamp,
  GRO_ID varchar(36),
  OBJECT_NAME varchar(255),
  OBJ_ID varchar(255),
  USER_NAME varchar(255),
  USER_ID varchar(255),
  EVENT_ID varchar(255),
  FINDINGS varchar(255),
  SUMMARY variant
);
```

This is my Sample data

```
ID  VERSION ACT_TYPE    EVE_TYPE    CLI_ID  DETAILS OBJ_TYPE    DATE_TIME   AAPP_EVENT_TO_UTC_DT    GRO_ID  OBJECT_NAME OBJ_ID  USER_NAME   USER_ID EVENT_ID    FINDINGS    SUMMARY

003cce70-ffff-43bc-8905-5e1d64475aa1    0   SCREENED_CASE   WORLDCHECK  0   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><testPayload><testId>565656-21cf-4c7e-8071-574a1ef78981</testId><testCode>COMPLETED</testCode><testState>TEST</testState><testResults>1</testResults><testRequiredResults>0</testRequiredResults><testExcludedResults>0</testExcludedResults><testAutoResolvedResults>1</testAutoResolvedResults><testproviderTypes>WATCHLIST</testproviderTypes></testPayload>  CASE    9/16/2020 9:45  9/16/2020 9:45  erutrt7-d726-4672-8599-83d21927bec5 0   5786765dfgdfgdfg    System User USER_SYSTEM 0   0   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><testCaseEventSummary><testTypes>WATCHLIST</testTypes><testResults>1</testResults></testCaseEventSummary>
```

I am to  create table with above DDL but when i insert it throws error
But when i declare all data type as `varchar` i am able to insert rows into this table

Can you please suggest what i am missing .

This is how i am trying to load data into table

```
COPY INTO demo_db.public.app_event
FROM @my_s3_stage/
FILES = ('Event_data.csv')
file_format=(type='CSV');
```

Comment: `9/16/2020 9:45` - I guess it i unknown timestamp literal and implicit conversion fails try: `'2020-09-16 09:45:00'::timestamp` instead

Comment: It looks like version is being set to the letter 'o' and I assume it should be zero

Comment: "help me with XML element query " - this sounds like a new question. If it is then please raise a new question, provide some sample data, the required result you are trying to achieve and show what you have already tried

Comment: @NickW thanks ..Created new question for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67249112/getting-xml-element-from-variant-column-of-a-snwoflake-table

Comment: @NickW i have zero in version filed now still getting same error `Numeric value 'VERSION' is not recognized File 'SNOWFLAKE/Audit_Event_data.csv`

Comment: What has that csv file got to do with what you are doing? Are there parts of the process you are following that you haven't explained in your question?

Comment: @NickW This is copy command that i use to load into table updated question

Comment: Does your file have a header row in it? If so then your file format in your copy command doesn't allow for that

Comment: @NickW You awesome Yes It was because of the header.That error is gone now .I am getting error in parsing JSON .I am have XML data in that columns `DETAILS` but getting `Error parsing JSON` error

Answer (score 0):

> I am to create table with above DDL but when i insert it throws error But when i declare all data type as varchar i am able to insert rows into this table

This kind of error message indicates that there is implicit conversion that fails.

Most likely for column `AAPP_EVENT_TO_UTC_DT timestamp` the value `9/16/2020 9:45` is not recoginized.

For providing date/timestamps: `'2020-09-16 09:45:00'::timestamp` could be used or [TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(string_expr, format)](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_timestamp.html) function providing specific format.

Comment: I get `Error parsing JSON:` for xml field .I have checked xml is an valid file and does not have any null value also