# Getting xml Element from variant column of a Snwoflake table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This is my Sample data

```
ID  VERSION ACT_TYPE    EVE_TYPE    CLI_ID  DETAILS OBJ_TYPE    DATE_TIME   AAPP_EVENT_TO_UTC_DT    GRO_ID  OBJECT_NAME OBJ_ID  USER_NAME   USER_ID EVENT_ID    FINDINGS    SUMMARY

6tgbcrq9pfhj1ezsdo82mcrzz   o   SCREENED_CASE   WORLDCHECK  o   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><testPayload><testId>565656-21cf-4c7e-8071-574a1ef78981</testId><testCode>COMPLETED</testCode><testState>TEST</testState><testResults>1</testResults><testRequiredResults>0</testRequiredResults><testExcludedResults>0</testExcludedResults><testAutoResolvedResults>1</testAutoResolvedResults><testproviderTypes>WATCHLIST</testproviderTypes></testPayload>  CASE    9/16/2020 9:45  9/16/2020 9:45  erutrt7-d726-4672-8599-83d21927bec5 o   5786765dfgdfgdfg    System User USER_SYSTEM o   o   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><testCaseEventSummary><testTypes>WATCHLIST</testTypes><testResults>1</testResults></testCaseEventSummary>
```

I need to get ID ,testId from this table .

Please note testId is inside the DETAIL column which is an xml .

I was trying something like below but its not working

```
select DETAILS:"$" from  audit_event;
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert it to xml with [parse_xml](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/parse_xml.html) and then use the [xmlget](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/xmlget.html) function get the testId field like this:

```sql
select xmlget(parse_xml(details), 'testId'):"$"::varchar from audit_event
```

I assumed you wanted it back as a `varchar` so I put the `::varchar` at the end to do that.